# ListView background color is not white

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer

I am trying to create NavigationDrawer slide with ListView and the listview color is purple and not white.
This is my code:
*activity_main*:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listDrawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:cacheColorHint="@color/nliveo_white"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/nliveo_transparent"
            android:background="@color/nliveo_white"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

*MyAdapter*:

```
public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;

    private static final int NOT_SELECTED = -1;
    private int selectedPos = NOT_SELECTED;

    public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems){
        this.context = context;
        this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return navDrawerItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return navDrawerItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public void setSelection(int position) {
        if (selectedPos == position) {
            selectedPos = NOT_SELECTED;
        } else {
            selectedPos = position;
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
        }

        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowIcon);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowTitle);

        imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());
        txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

        if (position == selectedPos) {
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_bg_pressed);
        } else {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.list_item_bg_normal);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

and the style:
*list_item_bg_normal*:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:drawable="@color/nliveo_transparent" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@color/nliveo_transparent" />
    <item android:state_selected="false"
          android:drawable="@color/nliveo_white"/>
</selector>
```

*list_item_bg_pressed*:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:drawable="@color/nliveo_transparent" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@color/nliveo_transparent" />
    <item android:state_selected="false"
          android:drawable="@color/nliveo_gray"/>
</selector>
```

*color.xml*

```
<color name="nliveo_white">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="nliveo_gray">#e0e0e0</color>
    <color name="nliveo_black">#000000</color>
    <color name="nliveo_transparent">#00000000</color>
```

What am I doing wrong?The listview should be white and in selected state - gray.

Comment: 100% sure that the `@color/nliveo_white` refers to the one defined in `color.xml`? CTRL + Click on it refers to the correct one? Sound crazy but I can't find any other reason.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with the list_item_bg_pressed file.
For Listview To be White and Grey in Selected State
It Should Be Modified As :

bg_pressed

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_selected="true"
      android:drawable="@color/nliveo_gray" />
 <item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@color/nliveo_gray" />
 <item android:state_selected="false"
      android:drawable="@color/nliveo_transparent"/>
 </selector>
```

Comment: Not working, the pressed mode is OK, the normal mode is purple

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
I used the function `setBackgroundColor` instead of `setBackgroundResource`.
So the code should be :

```
if (position == selectedPos) {
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_bg_pressed);
        } else {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.list_item_bg_normal);
        }
```